# Remove Database settings of django using bash script

Tags: django, linux, bash

I am trying to create a bash script to create a boilerplate django project that suits for my company. I need to delete the `DATABASES` in `settings` and append new one.
The `DATABASES` is a python dictionary with structure

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

For this I tried something like this

```
sed -i -e "/DATABASES = {/,/}/d" settings.py
```

But it resulted in a trailing }.

The output is

```
}
```

I understood that the pattern it matches is for the first curly braces but not the second. What should be the approach for this.

Comment: Have you considered https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just append a new `DATABASE` Configuration at the end of settings? It will automatically override previous `DATABASE` configuration. I use like this:

```
    DBCONIG="DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': '${dbName}',
            'USER': '${dbUName}',
            'PASSWORD': '${dbPass}',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '3306',

        }
    }"
    echo $DBCONIG >> settings.py
```

Here I collection `dbName`, `dbUName` etc from shell input.

For cleaner implementation approach, I keep a `local_settings.py` which has user machine specific setups. Inside in `local_settings.py`, I put the user's DB configurations. and I import this file in `settings.py` like this:

```
try:
   from .local_settings import *
except:
   pass
```

Also, I usually put `local_settings.py` file in `.gitignore`, so that these settings are not pushed to repository.